# send arryofstring with php+nusoap

Tags: php, soap

I have a SOAP webservice with a arrayofstrings field called `newSettings`, I'm trying to send it as a normal array of string using nusoap but it isn't working, any advice?

My code:

```
$settings=array('password','composefontsize');
$param=array(
'EmailAddress'=> $userEmail,
'newSettings' => $settings 
);

$response=$this->client->call("GetRequestedUserSettings",$param);
```

My XML request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns6388="http://tempuri.org">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><GetRequestedUserSettings xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<AuthUserName>admin</AuthUserName>
<AuthPassword>XXXX</AuthPassword>
<EmailAddress>xxx@xxx</EmailAddress>
<requestedSettings></requestedSettings>
</GetRequestedUserSettings>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"
```

---

**Update**: I fixed it with `$settings = array('string' => $value1,...)`;

Comment: The solution should go as an answer so you can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the soap calls in:

```
try { 
    // ... 
} catch (SoapFault $e) { 
    echo $e->faultcode; 
}
```

This way if either you don't meet the WSDL specifications or the server times out you'll be aware of the problem. I believe this is a must when using SOAP.

Comment: the webservice accept the request but the newSettings tag is empty so my array isnt recognized.

Comment: i see you fixed it, congrats then